# make width of child components to be 100%

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe

I usually write something like this:

```
            <mx:VBox height="100%" width="155">
                <mx:Button label="b1" width="100%"/>
                <mx:Buttonlabel="b2" width="100%"/>                 
                <mx:Button label="b3" width="100%"/>
                <mx:Button label="b4" width="100%"/>
            </mx:VBox>
```

So I need all the child components to be 100%, anybody knows any other way of doing this, like without having to specify 100% for all children.

Comment: If all your children are buttons, you might want to consider using a ButtonBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe do it programmatically on load? Loop through direct children and set their widths, setting it to 100%